# MVC Route Map Got Exception on Html.RenderAction : No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 and this is My Route Map for all of the actions except `Home/index`:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "randomNumber",
                url: "{controller}/{randomNumber}/{action}",
                defaults: new { },
                constraints: new { randomNumber = @"\d+" }
            );
```

And for first page: `Home/Index` I don't want to use `{randomNumber}`

So the first solution I think is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

This route map solve my problem, but caused another problem that is: clients can access to other actions without `{randomNumber}`, but I just want the `Index` action of `Home` Controller accessed without random number.

The other Solution Is:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Default",
                     url: "Home/Index",
                     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
```

But with this map I can't access `Home/index` with root url, I need to access `Home/index` with root url like this: **www.mydomainaddress.com**

Finally i found this:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Default",
                     url: "",
                     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
```

But I got the Exception: `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.` on `index.cshtml` file in this line: `@{Html.RenderAction("ArchiveList", "Home");}`

I don't know the ralation of the route map that I added and `RenderAction` helper?

But If I add both the following two route maps, everything will be OK:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "Default",
                     url: "",
                     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );

 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "HomeActions",
               url: "Home/{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
           );
```

But I can't add the second map route as you know (I need all actions accessed with random number)

I can't understand what happened when I add the `Default` map, and what related to `RenderAction` helper?

Does any one have any idea about this? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have already used this syntax with MVC5 and it works :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomePage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

This syntax allows you to access your home page using `www.mydomainaddress.com` but it won't work if you try using `www.mydomainaddress.com/home/index`

I don't see why it doesn't work for you. You can try rearanging the order or the MapRoutes definitions (place the "HomePage" route after the "randomNumber" route)

I saw your modified question. I understand you want to be able to use any action for the home controller and don't want to be able to use the randomNumber for the HomeController.

This probably will fit you better (also disabling the randomNumber route for Home controller) :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
               name: "HomePage",
               url: "",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HomeActions",
                url: "Home/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "randomNumber",
           url: "{controller}/{randomNumber}/{action}",
           defaults: new { },
           constraints: new { randomNumber = @"\d+", controller = @"^((?!Home).)*$" }
       );
```

Comment: I got this Exception: `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.`

Comment: Can you post your whole RouteConfig class?

Comment: With your answer the other actions in home Controller accessed without `randomNumber` that I mentioned in question I don't want accessed.